# How to 'insert' values in tags using Zend Decorators

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

Please advise on inserting values such as '#', 'Name' and 'Number' between the   HTML tags as shown using Zend Form Decorators. Thanks

```
      <thead>
             <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Number</th>
             </tr>
      </thead>
```

Edit:
@Asuraya To clarify: I have been able to generate the desired structure above with the decorator code below. However, it renders without the '#', 'Name' and 'Number' within the  tags. I have not been able to figure out a way of inserting values.

```
      $subform->setDecorators(array(
     'FormElements',
      array(array('th1' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'th')),
      array(array('th2' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'th')),
      array(array('th3' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'th')),
      array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),
      array(array('thead' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'thead')),
      array(array('tbody' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tbody', 'placement' => 'APPEND')),
      array(array('table' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'table', 'id' => 'tabdata')),
      'Form',
     ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not clear.
If you want show value with form using view script.

```
$thead = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('thead');
$thead->setDecorators(
     array(
    array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'thead.phtml'))
    )
);
```

thead.phtml is

```
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Number</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```